# How to truncate a date to Friday based on week of month?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, datetime, pyspark

I have a below dataframe that contains year, month and weeks and I need to create a column date (as shown below) from the year, month and weeks columns and consider week end as on Friday.

```
Year    Month   Weeks   date
2018    April   01 W    2018-04-06
2018    April   02 W    2018-04-13
2018    April   03 W    2018-04-20
2018    April   04 W    2018-04-27
2018    May     01 W    2018-05-04
2018    May     02 W    2018-05-11
2018    May     03 W    2018-05-18
2018    May     04 W    2018-05-25
2018    June    01 W    2018-06-01
```

Please can someone advise on how to achieve that in pyspark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without any `udf`s. The logic should be as follows:

1. Use the `Year` and `Month` column to create a `DateType()` column using [`concat`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat) and [`to_date`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.to_date). The day will be the first of the month (`lit("01")`).
2. Truncate this date using [`date_trunc`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.date_trunc) with `"week"` as the `format` argument. This will return a date which corresponds to the most recent Monday occurring prior to the current date.
3. If we add 4 days to the result of step 2, we will land on a Friday. Then we should be able to add in `7` times the number in the `Weeks` column to get the desired date. However, there is an edge case that we need to account for: in some cases, the truncated date + 4 days will be in the previous month. In that case, we need to add an extra 7 days.

Here it is in code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, concat, date_add, date_trunc
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr, lit, month, substring, to_date, when

def truncate_date(year, month):
    """Assumes year and month are columns"""
    dt = concat(year, month, lit("01"))
    return date_trunc("week", (to_date(dt, "yyyyMMMdd"))).cast("date")

def get_days_to_add(truncated_date, weeks):
    """If the truncated date + 4 days is in the same month, 
    we need to skip ahead one extra week"""
    return when(
        month(date_add(truncated_date, 4)) == month(truncated_date),
        (substring(weeks, 1, 2).cast("int"))*7 + 4
    ).otherwise((substring(weeks, 1, 2).cast("int")-1)*7 + 4)

df.withColumn("truncated_date", truncate_date(col("Year"), col("Month")))\
    .withColumn("days_to_add", get_days_to_add(col("truncated_date"), col("Weeks")))\
    .withColumn("final_date", expr("date_add(truncated_date, days_to_add)"))\
    .show()
#+----+-----+-----+----------+--------------+-----------+----------+
#|Year|Month|Weeks|      date|truncated_date|days_to_add|final_date|
#+----+-----+-----+----------+--------------+-----------+----------+
#|2018|April|  01W|2018-04-06|    2018-03-26|         11|2018-04-06|
#|2018|April|  02W|2018-04-13|    2018-03-26|         18|2018-04-13|
#|2018|April|  03W|2018-04-20|    2018-03-26|         25|2018-04-20|
#|2018|April|  04W|2018-04-27|    2018-03-26|         32|2018-04-27|
#|2018|  May|  01W|2018-05-04|    2018-04-30|          4|2018-05-04|
#|2018|  May|  02W|2018-05-11|    2018-04-30|         11|2018-05-11|
#|2018|  May|  03W|2018-05-18|    2018-04-30|         18|2018-05-18|
#|2018|  May|  04W|2018-05-25|    2018-04-30|         25|2018-05-25|
#|2018| June|  01W|2018-06-01|    2018-05-28|          4|2018-06-01|
#+----+-----+-----+----------+--------------+-----------+----------+
```

You can drop the intermediate columns, but I have left them to illustrate the logic and steps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to solve this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from pyspark.sql.types import *

df = spark.createDataFrame([(2018, 'April', '01 W'), 
                            (2018, 'April', '02 W'), 
                            (2018, 'April', '03 W'),
                            (2018, 'April', '04 W'),
                            (2018, 'May', '01 W'),
                            (2018, 'May', '02 W'),
                            (2018, 'May', '03 W'),
                            (2018, 'May', '04 W'),
                            (2018, 'June', '01 W')
                           ], 
                           ["Year", "Month", "Weeks"])

df = df.withColumn('week_number', F.regexp_extract(df['Weeks'], r'(\d+) ',1).cast(IntegerType()))
md = {'April':'04', 'May':'05', 'June':'06'}
df = df.withColumn('month_number', F.udf(lambda r: md[r])(df['Month']))
df = df.withColumn('yyyymm', F.concat_ws('-', df['Year'], df['month_number']))
df = df.withColumn('first_date', F.to_date(df['yyyymm'], 'yyyy-MM'))
df = df.withColumn('first_date', F.date_sub(df['first_date'], 1))
df = df.withColumn('first_date', F.next_day(df['first_date'], 'Fri'))
df = df.withColumn('date', F.lit(''))

df.show()
@pandas_udf(df.schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def _calc_fri(pdf):
    s = pd.to_datetime(pdf['first_date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d')
    days = s + pd.to_timedelta((pdf['week_number']-1)*7, unit='day')
    pdf['date'] = days.dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    return pdf
df = df.groupby(['Year', 'Month']).apply(_calc_fri).orderBy(['Year', 'month_number', 'week_number'])

df.show()
```

The outputs:

```
+----+-----+-----+-----------+------------+-------+----------+----------+
|Year|Month|Weeks|week_number|month_number| yyyymm|first_date|      date|
+----+-----+-----+-----------+------------+-------+----------+----------+
|2018|April| 01 W|          1|          04|2018-04|2018-04-06|2018-04-06|
|2018|April| 02 W|          2|          04|2018-04|2018-04-06|2018-04-13|
|2018|April| 03 W|          3|          04|2018-04|2018-04-06|2018-04-20|
|2018|April| 04 W|          4|          04|2018-04|2018-04-06|2018-04-27|
|2018|  May| 01 W|          1|          05|2018-05|2018-05-04|2018-05-04|
|2018|  May| 02 W|          2|          05|2018-05|2018-05-04|2018-05-11|
|2018|  May| 03 W|          3|          05|2018-05|2018-05-04|2018-05-18|
|2018|  May| 04 W|          4|          05|2018-05|2018-05-04|2018-05-25|
|2018| June| 01 W|          1|          06|2018-06|2018-06-01|2018-06-01|
+----+-----+-----+-----------+------------+-------+----------+----------+
```

Guess you can also put all the work into the `pandas_udf`, or use `udf`, I personally will try to do less work in any `udf`.

Comment: You don't need a `udf` to convert the `"Month"` to a date- you can use the [Java `SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Pretty sure there's a way to do that with `pandas.to_datetime` as well.

Comment: @pault You are probably right, I am not familiar with java SimpleDateFormat.